# Install uWSGI PHP Plugin on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, plugins, uwsgi

According to their documentation [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PHP.html) in order to run `PHP` scripts with `uWSGI` the `uwsgi php` plugin should be installed. However their documentation point only how to do it on `Ubuntu 10.04`, not hints at all on how to install it on `12.04`. There is a package for `13.10` which does not work in our case.

Did somebody else solved it somehow and brought this plugin up and running on a `12.04` system?